# py2exe missing pandas file

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I'm trying to compile a python script in vrs 2.7.13 to an executable file using py2exe (my only option atm)

running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 42, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\api.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\groupby\__init__.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\groupby\groupby.pyc", line 37, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\frame.pyc", line 100, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\series.pyc", line 4390, in <module>
  File "pandas\core\generic.pyc", line 10138, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
  File "pandas\core\window.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\window.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\window.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "pandas\_libs\skiplist.pyd", line 31, in init pandas._libs.window
ImportError: No module named skiplist
```

command: python.exe setup.py py2exe

setup.py code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

Mydata_files = [('pandas\_libs\skiplist.pxd', ['E:\python2.7.13\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\skiplist.pyd'])] 
setup(
        windows=['test.py'],
        data_files=Mydata_files,
        options={
                "py2exe":{
                        "includes": ["pandas","bs4","requests","lxml","csv"]
                }
        }
)
```

Comment: Same problem, did you solve it?